# Opening Bootsfaces page in Eclipse browser or Mobile browser causes "Opening and ending tag mismatch: li"

Tags: html, eclipse, jsf, mobile, bootsfaces

I am trying to create a application with bootsfaces.

while rendering page in Mozilla or chrome , everything looks fine.
when i render in inbuilt browser in eclipse or browser in mobile i am getting following error

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 8 at column 1488: Opening and ending tag mismatch: li
>   line 0 and ul Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I am unable to identify the issue. because i am unable to check html source in both case.

Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you include some of your code or the rendered HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: use [Validator](http://validator.w3.org) an select "Show Source"